# Sql Inner join with removing id prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table **tblEsslAttendance** and **tblEnquiry** in tblDevicemember id generate 111 and tblMember id generate JE-111, I want to join that two table with this id base

My table **tblEsslAttendance** are:

```
 EmpDeviceCode | EmpCode | LogDate
 -----------------------------------
 111           |   111   |2017-02-03
```

my table **tblEnquiry** are

```
EnquiryID | FirstName | Gender
   -----------------------------
JE-111    |   AAAA    | Male
```

I try to solve this issue my query was:

```
SELECT l.EmpDeviceCode,(RIGHT(ah.EnquiryID, LEN(ah.EnquiryID) - 3)) 
AS tempnewId, 
ah.*  FROM tblEnquiry ah INNER JOIN tblEsslAttendance 
l ON l.EmpCode = ah.tempnewId
```

Can you help me?

I want an output like this:

```
EmpDeviceCode | EmpCode | LogDate  |EnquiryID |FirstName | Gender
------------------------------------------------------------------
111           |   111   |2017-02-03|JE-111    | AAAAA    | Male
```

Comment: Your design doesn't look particularly good here. If your `EnquiryID` should link to the `EmpCode` in this way, then there should probably be an `EmpCode` as a foreign key in `tblEnquiry`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `substring()` with `charindex()` function to get the id only

```
SELECT * FROM tblDeviceMember d
INNER JOIN tblMember m ON 
      substring(m.EnquiryID, charindex('-', m.EnquiryID)+1, len(m.EnquiryID)) = d.EmpCode
```

Same *lookup* table also could useful, if you don't want to repeat the expression via  `SUBSTRING()`

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT *,
              substring(m.EnquiryID, charindex('-', m.EnquiryID)+1, len(m.EnquiryID)) Id
      FROM tblMember 
) m INNER JOIN tblDeviceMember d ON d.EmpCode = m.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use column aliases from the `select` in the query at the same level -- including the `on` clause.

One method puts the logic in the `on`:

```
SELECT l.EmpDeviceCode,
       (RIGHT(ah.EnquiryID, LEN(ah.EnquiryID) - 3)) AS tempnewId, 
       ah.* 
FROM tblEnquiry ah INNER JOIN
     tblEsslAttendance l
     ON l.EmpCode = (RIGHT(ah.EnquiryID, LEN(ah.EnquiryID) - 3));
```

If you don't want to repeat the expression, you can use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join:

```
SELECT l.EmpDeviceCode, v.tempnewId, 
       ah.* 
FROM tblEsslAttendance l CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (RIGHT(ah.EnquiryID, LEN(ah.EnquiryID) - 3) ) v(tempnewId)
     tblEnquiry ah 
     ON l.EmpCode = v.tempnewid;
```