# POSTGRES: Inner join with removing id prefix

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have two tables, one is an instrument_static table that looks like this

```
 epic|  name     | Updated
 -----------------------------------
 ABC |   Google |2017-02-03
```

The other table is market_data that looks like this

```
 epic       | name     | Updated
 -----------------------------------
 MARKET:ABC |   Google |2017-02-03
```

I want to join both tables using the epic but note the epic in market_data will always be prefixed with "MARKET:".Can someone kindly assist

I believe this query is identical to this one: 
[Sql Inner join with removing id prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234987/sql-inner-join-with-removing-id-prefix)

However, as I am dealing with Postgress I have read charindex is not a supported function.

This is what I have managed to come up with so far which currently brings back an error:

SELECT * FROM instrument_static s
INNER JOIN market_data m ON 
      substring(m.epic, charindex(':', M.epic)+1, len(m.epic)) = s.epic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string concatenation in the `join` clause:

```
select . . . 
from instrument_static ins join
     market_data md
     on md.epic = 'MARKET:' || ins.epic and
        md.name = ins.name and
        md.updated = ins.updated;
```

There are similar methods to accomplish this using `split()`, `like`, regular expression matching, and so on.